# Modifying Binary Search to Find then Delete

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am very new to programming, and I am working with the C++ language. This is for my homework, and is using binary search trees. What I am trying to do is create a function called find_node, which later then calls a function called delete_node. This is what the teacher gave as a prompt for the find_node function.

Prompt from professor:

Add `void find_node( const T &val )`
      method to the class Node to find the node that contains val;
         if you do not find, there is nothing to do
         if you find it and p is Node * that points to it,
            delete p by calling `delete_node( Node< T > *&p )`.

`void delete_node( Node< T > *&p )`
      method to remove node p from a binary tree

File given by professor

`btree.h`

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    "node.h"
//using namespace std;

template < typename elemType >
class BinaryTree {
  public:
BinaryTree( );
~BinaryTree( );
void insert( const elemType & );
void remove( const elemType & );
void inorder( );
bool empty( );
void clear( );

private:
Node< elemType >    *_root;

BinaryTree( const BinaryTree & );
BinaryTree &operator =( const BinaryTree & );
void clear( Node< elemType > * );
};

template < typename elemType >
inline BinaryTree< elemType >::BinaryTree( ) : _root(0)
{
    cout << "BinaryTree::BinaryTree() "
       << "default constructor\n";
}

template < typename elemType >
inline BinaryTree< elemType >::~BinaryTree( )
{
   cout << "BinaryTree::~BinaryTree() destructor\n";
   clear( );
}

template < typename elemType >
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::clear( )
{
   if( _root )
   {
      clear( _root );
      _root = 0;
   }
}

template < typename elemType >
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::clear( Node< elemType > *pt )
{
   if( pt ) {
      cout << "clear( ) left of  "  << pt->value( ) << '\n';
      clear( pt->left( ) );
      cout << "clear( ) right of " << pt->value( ) << '\n';
      clear( pt->right( ) );
      delete pt;
    }
}

template < typename elemType >
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::insert( const elemType &e )
{
   if( !_root )
   {
      _root = new Node< elemType >( e );
   }
   else
   {
      _root->insert_value( e );
   }
}

template < typename elemType >
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::remove( const elemType &e )
{
  _root->find_node( _root, e );
}

template < typename elemType>
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::inorder( )
{
   _root->inorder( _root );
   cout << '\n';
}
```

Given by professor, but is the file I have to add the 2 methods to from the prompt

`node.h`

```
#ifndef     NODE_H

#define     NODE_H

#include    <string>

using namespace std;

template< typename T >
class Node
{
  public:
      Node( const T &);

      T  value( )  const;
      T  value( const T & );

      void insert_value( const T & );
      void inorder( const Node * );
      void find_node( const T &val, const T* root );
    //bool find_node( const T &val, Node < T > *node) const;
      void delete_node( Node< T > *&p );

      Node *  left ( ) const;
      Node *  left ( Node * );
      Node *  right( ) const;
      Node *  right( Node * );

   private:
      T       _value;
      Node *  _left;
      Node *  _right;
      Node< T > * root; //point to root node
      Node::Node( const Node & );
      Node &operator =( const Node & );



};


template< typename T >
inline Node< T >::Node( const T &rhs )
{
   _value = rhs;                       // assign rhs to _value
   _left  =  _right = 0;               // node is not part of a tree yet
}


template< typename T >
inline T Node< T >::value( ) const
{
   return _value;
}


template< typename T >
inline T Node< T >::value( const T &rhs )
{
   _value = rhs;                       // new value for _value
   return _value;
}


template< typename T >
inline Node< T > *Node< T >::left( ) const
{
   return _left;
}


template< typename T >
inline Node< T > *Node< T >::left( Node< T > *rhs )
{
   _left = rhs;

   return _left;
}


template< typename T >
inline Node< T > *Node< T >::right( ) const
{
   return _right;
}


template< typename T >
inline Node< T > *Node< T >::right( Node< T > *rhs )
{
   _right = rhs;
   return _right;
}


template< typename T >
inline void Node< T >::insert_value( const T &val )
{
    if( val == _value )
{
    return;                     // value already in the tree
}
if( val < _value )              // val should appear at the left
{
    if( ! _left )               // no left subtree ?
    {                           // add new node here
        _left = new Node( val );
    }
    else                        // try the subtree
    {
        _left->insert_value( val );
    }
}
else                            // val should appear at the right
{
    if( ! _right )              // no right subtree ?
    {                           // add new node here
        _right = new Node( val );
    }
    else                        // try the subtree
    {
        _right->insert_value( val );
    }
  }
}


template< typename T >
inline void Node< T >::inorder( const Node< T > *pt )
{
   if( pt )
   {
      inorder( pt->_left );
      cout << std::hex << pt->_left << std::dec << '\t';
      cout << std::hex << pt << std::dec << '\t';
      cout << std::hex << pt->_right << std::dec << '\t';
      cout << pt->_value << '\n';
      inorder( pt->_right );
   }
}


template <typename T>
Node<T> const * find_node(const T &val)
{
   Node<T> const * curr = root;
   while( curr != 0 )
   {
      if (val == curr -> _value)  {
       break;
    }
    else if (val < curr -> _value) {
        curr = curr -> _left;
    |
    else {
        curr = curr -> _right;
    }
}
return curr;
}
}

template <typename T >
inline void find_node( const T & val, const T * root ) {
Node<T> const * ptrFoundNode = find_node_pointer( val, root );
if( ptrFoundNode ) {
    delete_node( ptrFoundNode, root );
  }
}

template< typename T >
inline void Node< T >::delete_node(Node < T > *&p)
{

Node<T> *curr, *prev, *temp;
   if (p == NULL) return;
   if (p->_left == NULL && p->_right == NULL) {
    // no children - easy
    // *** if allowing counted duplicates:
    // ***    if (p->getCount() > 1) (*p)--;
    // ***    else {
       temp = p;
       p = NULL;
       delete temp;
    }
 else if (p->_left == NULL) {
    // only a right child - still easy
    // *** if allowing counted duplicates:
    // ***    if (p->getCount() > 1) (*p)--;
    // ***    else {
       temp = p;
       p = temp->_right;
       delete temp;
    }
 else if (p->_right == NULL) {
    // only a left child - still easy
    // *** if allowing counted duplicates:
    // ***    if (p->getCount() > 1) (*p)--;
    // ***    else {
       temp = p;
       p = temp->_left;
       delete temp;
    }
 else {
    // two children - this is the hard case
    // use successor: once right, then as far left as possible
    // *** if allowing counted duplicates:
    // ***    if (p->getCount() > 1) (*p)--;
    // ***    else {
       curr = p->_right;
       prev = NULL;
       while (curr->_left != NULL) {
           prev = curr;
           curr = curr->left;
       }
       p->data = curr->data;
       if (prev == NULL) p->_right = curr->_right;
       else prev->_left = curr->_right;

       delete curr;
   }
}


#endif
```

Comment: Should not `find_node()` return something rather than void? If it returns `curr` then the caller can call `delete_node()` on that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin so far, it's not compiling. I've been trying to code this a few different ways, but I cannot seem to get anything working. For right now, i'm missing another argument. I'm trying to get past that error message, so I can see what else is wrong or other error messages i am receiving

Comment: @ArunSaha that is how the professor gave that function. The declaration was given to us by the professor, all we have to do is code it.

Comment: @bob Glenn: I see, it was not clear enough to me. I have provided an answer. I am still not sure if I understood your requirements correctly (it might help if you can provide the signature of `find_node()` and `delete_node()` as your professor wants it), please check it out and comment there.

Comment: @ArunSaha what would a signature look like?

Answer (score 0):

Following is a sketch with minimum changes to OP's code:

```
Node<T> const * find_node_pointer( Node<T> const * root, T const & val)
{
    Node<T> const * curr = root;
    while( curr != 0 )
    {
        if (val == curr -> _value)  {
           break;
        }
        else if (val < curr -> _value) {
            curr = curr -> _left;
        |
        else {
            curr = curr -> _right;
        }
    }
    return curr;
}
```

Caller:

```
void find_node( Node<T> const * root, T const & val ) {
    Node<T> const * ptrFoundNode = find_node_pointer( root, val );
    if( ptrFoundNode ) {
        delete_node( root, ptrFoundNode );
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, still missing one more argument. I will edit the original code and include one instance where my find_node function is being called in another header file

Comment: Deleting a `const` node pointer out of a tree should be interesting once it has been pruned. Planning on `const_cast`'ing that? if not, releasing the underlying node may prove difficult.

Comment: @WhozCraig i'm not sure if i know what you really mean

Comment: @bob: I am trying, but still the requirements and the question is not fully clear.. You have to help us be clarifying the main problem statement, what you attempted so far, what is blocking you etc. @WhozCraig: Good point. `delete_node()` may be able to handle that. We are still struggling with the overall requirements ;-)

Comment: @ArunSaha I am sorry for not being as clear as I can be. This homework assignment has got me really frustrated. Would it be easier if I put all the files up?

Comment: @ArunSaha with the coding that you have provided for me, when find_node() is being called in the btree.h file, i receive an error message saying that "cannot convert from Node<T>* to const int &"

Comment: @bob: You may have to make changes in your code to match my latest code. I had to modify my code few times based on information provided by you. Look at my code carefully :-)

Comment: @ArunSaha Yes, I would have to make changes, I understand that. I've been looking at your code as well, using as a sample. But could you help me locate where the const int & is. I have been looking through the code, and have not been able to find it. The error is located at the remove function in btree.h. I cannot seem to understand this error

Comment: @ArunSaha actually, I found where the conversions are happening. It is occurring in the cpp files that I didn't put post on here. But how I still get the error, where it is saying that cannot convert const T &val from Node<T> * to "const int". How do I fix this. Cannot seem ti think of how to fix this