# Binary Search Tree error converting from template to const int

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am doing homework and I am try to implement some binary search tree functions. I am also very new to programming, and do not have much experience with programming. I have the functions written out, but I am tring to figure out the error that I am receiving. The error that I am receiving is `btree.h(76): error C2664: 'Node<T>::find_node' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Node<T> *' to 'const int &'
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
          Reason: cannot convert from 'Node<T> *' to 'const int'
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]`

This is the reason why I put the cpp files as well. Get an error in the cpp files as well. All files were provided by my professor. I only had to add 2 methods to node.h, and that was it. This is the error in the cpp file tree2.cpp

`tree2.cpp(28) : see reference to class template instantiation 'BinaryTree<elemType>' being compiled
          with
          [
             elemType=int
         ]`

If anyone could help out explain how to fix the error with suggestions would be great.

btree.h

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    "node.h"
//using namespace std;

template < typename elemType >
class BinaryTree {
  public:
BinaryTree( );
~BinaryTree( );
void insert( const elemType & );
void remove( const elemType & );
void inorder( );
bool empty( );
void clear( );

private:
Node< elemType >    *_root;

BinaryTree( const BinaryTree & );
BinaryTree &operator =( const BinaryTree & );
void clear( Node< elemType > * );
};

template < typename elemType >
inline BinaryTree< elemType >::BinaryTree( ) : _root(0)
{
    cout << "BinaryTree::BinaryTree() "
       << "default constructor\n";
}

template < typename elemType >
inline BinaryTree< elemType >::~BinaryTree( )
{
   cout << "BinaryTree::~BinaryTree() destructor\n";
   clear( );
}

template < typename elemType >
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::clear( )
{
   if( _root )
   {
      clear( _root );
      _root = 0;
   }
}

template < typename elemType >
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::clear( Node< elemType > *pt )
{
   if( pt ) {
      cout << "clear( ) left of  "  << pt->value( ) << '\n';
      clear( pt->left( ) );
      cout << "clear( ) right of " << pt->value( ) << '\n';
      clear( pt->right( ) );
      delete pt;
    }
}

template < typename elemType >
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::insert( const elemType &e )
{
   if( !_root )
   {
      _root = new Node< elemType >( e );
   }
   else
   {
      _root->insert_value( e );
   }
}

template < typename elemType >
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::remove( const elemType &e )
{
  _root->find_node( _root, e );
}

template < typename elemType>
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::inorder( )
{
   _root->inorder( _root );
   cout << '\n';
}
```

`node.h`

```
#ifndef     NODE_H

#define     NODE_H

#include    <string>

using namespace std;

template< typename T >
class Node
{
  public:
      Node( const T &);

      T  value( )  const;
      T  value( const T & );

      void insert_value( const T & );
      void inorder( const Node * );
      void find_node( const T &val, const T* root );
    //bool find_node( const T &val, Node < T > *node) const;
      void delete_node( Node< T > *&p );

      Node *  left ( ) const;
      Node *  left ( Node * );
      Node *  right( ) const;
      Node *  right( Node * );

   private:
      T       _value;
      Node *  _left;
      Node *  _right;
      Node< T > * root; //point to root node
      Node::Node( const Node & );
      Node &operator =( const Node & );



};


template< typename T >
inline Node< T >::Node( const T &rhs )
{
   _value = rhs;                       // assign rhs to _value
   _left  =  _right = 0;               // node is not part of a tree yet
}


template< typename T >
inline T Node< T >::value( ) const
{
   return _value;
}


template< typename T >
inline T Node< T >::value( const T &rhs )
{
   _value = rhs;                       // new value for _value
   return _value;
}


template< typename T >
inline Node< T > *Node< T >::left( ) const
{
   return _left;
}


template< typename T >
inline Node< T > *Node< T >::left( Node< T > *rhs )
{
   _left = rhs;

   return _left;
}


template< typename T >
inline Node< T > *Node< T >::right( ) const
{
   return _right;
}


template< typename T >
inline Node< T > *Node< T >::right( Node< T > *rhs )
{
   _right = rhs;
   return _right;
}


template< typename T >
inline void Node< T >::insert_value( const T &val )
{
    if( val == _value )
{
    return;                     // value already in the tree
}
if( val < _value )              // val should appear at the left
{
    if( ! _left )               // no left subtree ?
    {                           // add new node here
        _left = new Node( val );
    }
    else                        // try the subtree
    {
        _left->insert_value( val );
    }
}
else                            // val should appear at the right
{
    if( ! _right )              // no right subtree ?
    {                           // add new node here
        _right = new Node( val );
    }
    else                        // try the subtree
    {
        _right->insert_value( val );
    }
  }
}


template< typename T >
inline void Node< T >::inorder( const Node< T > *pt )
{
   if( pt )
   {
      inorder( pt->_left );
      cout << std::hex << pt->_left << std::dec << '\t';
      cout << std::hex << pt << std::dec << '\t';
      cout << std::hex << pt->_right << std::dec << '\t';
      cout << pt->_value << '\n';
      inorder( pt->_right );
   }
}


template <typename T>
Node<T> const * find_node(const T &val)
{
   Node<T> const * curr = root;
   while( curr != 0 )
   {
      if (val == curr -> _value)  {
       break;
    }
    else if (val < curr -> _value) {
        curr = curr -> _left;
    |
    else {
        curr = curr -> _right;
    }
}
return curr;
}
}

template <typename T >
inline void find_node( const T & val, const T * root ) {
Node<T> const * ptrFoundNode = find_node_pointer( val, root );
if( ptrFoundNode ) {
    delete_node( ptrFoundNode, root );
  }
}

template< typename T >
inline void Node< T >::delete_node(Node < T > *&p)
{

Node<T> *curr, *prev, *temp;
   if (p == NULL) return;
   if (p->_left == NULL && p->_right == NULL) {
    // no children - easy
    // *** if allowing counted duplicates:
    // ***    if (p->getCount() > 1) (*p)--;
    // ***    else {
       temp = p;
       p = NULL;
       delete temp;
    }
 else if (p->_left == NULL) {
    // only a right child - still easy
    // *** if allowing counted duplicates:
    // ***    if (p->getCount() > 1) (*p)--;
    // ***    else {
       temp = p;
       p = temp->_right;
       delete temp;
    }
 else if (p->_right == NULL) {
    // only a left child - still easy
    // *** if allowing counted duplicates:
    // ***    if (p->getCount() > 1) (*p)--;
    // ***    else {
       temp = p;
       p = temp->_left;
       delete temp;
    }
 else {
    // two children - this is the hard case
    // use successor: once right, then as far left as possible
    // *** if allowing counted duplicates:
    // ***    if (p->getCount() > 1) (*p)--;
    // ***    else {
       curr = p->_right;
       prev = NULL;
       while (curr->_left != NULL) {
           prev = curr;
           curr = curr->left;
       }
       p->data = curr->data;
       if (prev == NULL) p->_right = curr->_right;
       else prev->_left = curr->_right;

       delete curr;
   }
}


#endif
```

`tree2.cpp`

```
#include    "btree.h"
#include    <fstream>
#include    <string>

using namespace std;


ifstream get_ifs( )                             // get input file stream
{
   string filename;                            // input file name

   cerr << "name of file to read from? ";
   cin  >> filename;

   ifstream ifs( filename, ifstream::in );
   if( ! ifs )                                 // cannot open file infilen
   {
      cerr << "cannot open input file '" << filename << "'\n";
      exit( 1 );
   }

   return ifs;                                 // return input file stream
}


int main()
{
   BinaryTree< int > bt;

   bt.insert( 30 );
   bt.insert( 20 );
   bt.insert( 40 );
   bt.insert( 50 );
   bt.insert( 10 );
   bt.insert( 15 );
   bt.insert( 35 );

   cout << "inorder traversal:\n";
   bt.inorder( );

   ifstream ifs = get_ifs( );

   string cmd;
   int    value;

   while( ifs >> cmd )
   {
      ifs >> value;

      cout << cmd << '\t' << value << '\n';

      if( cmd == "a" )
      {
          bt.insert( value );
      }
      else if( cmd == "d" )
      {
          bt.remove( value );
       }
      else
      {
          cout << "invalid command '" << cmd << "' ignored...\n\n";
      }

      bt.inorder( );
      cout << '\n';
   }

   return 0;
}
```

`tree1.cpp`

```
#include    "btree.h"
#include    <fstream>
#include    <string>

using namespace std;


ifstream get_ifs( )                             // get input file stream
{
   string filename;                            // input file name

   cerr << "name of file to read from? ";
   cin  >> filename;

   ifstream ifs( filename, ifstream::in );
   if( ! ifs )                                 // cannot open file infilen
   {
      cerr << "cannot open input file '" << filename << "'\n";
      exit( 1 );
   }

   return ifs;                                 // return input file stream
}


int main()
{
   BinaryTree< string > bt;

   bt.insert( "Florida" );
   bt.insert( "California" );
   bt.insert( "Alabama" );
   bt.insert( "Mississippi" );
   bt.insert( "Georgia" );
   bt.insert( "Colorado" );
   bt.insert( "Idaho" );
   bt.insert( "Missouri" );
   bt.insert( "New York" );

   cout << "inorder traversal:\n";
   bt.inorder( );

   ifstream ifs = get_ifs( );

   string cmd, value;
   while( ifs >> cmd )
   {
      ifs >> value;

      cout << cmd << '\t' << value << '\n';

      if( cmd == "a" )
      {
          bt.insert( value );
      }
      else if( cmd == "d" )
      {
          bt.remove( value );
      }
      else
      {
          cout << "invalid command '" << cmd << "' ignored...\n\n";
      }

      bt.inorder( );
      cout << '\n';
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello Bob, welcoe to StackOverflow. If you want us to help you with your code, you should get in the habit of posting *minimal examples*. That means whittle down your code to the smallest example that compiles and produces the error. It's a good skill to learn for your own use too.

Comment: @Beta sorry that my code is not compiling. That is what I am trying to fix so that it does compile. I am receiving this error, and trying to figure out how to fix it

Comment: Sorry, that was careless of me. What I meant in this case was the smallest example that produces that error and no other.

Comment: I understand. the reason i provide all files is because the cpp files is where my variable named value is being assigned a data type of int. i figured it would be helpful to include the cpp files as well

Comment: Bob, offhand how much of this is *your* implementation? Was just the header declarations provided and you had to provide the template member bodies?

Comment: @WhozCraig what I am implementing is the find_node function and the delete_node function. They are both in the node.h file. Everything pertaining to those two functions in node.h is what I am trying to implement

Comment: @bobGlenn Ok, but again, was **everything else** including the *prototypes* for those two members provided for you from someone/something else? Are those the only code you've touched in these files?

Comment: Everything was provided by the professor. He even provided the function prototypes. But the function prototype he provided for find_node is different compared to what i currently have. This is the original prototype for the find_node function
`void find_node( const T &val )`

Comment: @WhozCraig also if this helps, this is what the professor sent to me when I asked for help:
`Your find_node in your node.h needs to have two arguments. 
You've got one (the val that you are searching for), but you should also be receiving the pointer to the node to start searching with.

Initially, that is the root.
find_node should be a binary search, that decends down the left or right side of the tree, executing itself until val == p->value(), when it deletes p and leaves`

Comment: Didn't *he* provide the original prototype? Now he's saying its wrong? Frankly, I don't think your instructor has both oars in the water. find_node(), by definition, is a **Node member function**. It literally makes ZERO sense to pass a node pointer to this function. It also makes ZERO sense to be *deleting* a node through a method called `find_node()`. Your instructor, TA, or whoever sent you those comments is either confused between BinaryTree members and Node members, didn't understand the question, or needs to seriously seek help for their substance abuse problem.

Comment: Side note: the copy-constructor private decl in class Node is wrong. It reads `Node::Node(const Node&)` It should be `Node(const Node&);`. Seriously, sir, your instructor *must* be a PhD.

Comment: @WhozCraig 'const Node &" and 'Node const &" means exactly the same :-)

Comment: @ArunSaha Look at that comment again. `const Node&` and `Node const &` are indeed the same (and I never claimed they were different), but *within the class definition*, `Node(const Node&)` and **`Node::Node(const Node&)`** are **not**.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Perhaps I misunderstood your comment, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the following line from

```
inline void find_node(  const T & val, const T * root ) {
```

to

```
inline void find_node( const T * root, const T & val ) {
```

help?

See also: [Modifying Binary Search to Find then Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794296/modifying-binary-search-to-find-then-delete)

Comment: I've tried that already. But the teacher says that we need 2 arguments. The only file the professor wants us to change is the node.h file

Answer (score 0):

The `find_node` method wants the `T` type not a node; it wants the type of data in the node.

You are passing it the whole node when it doesn't want that.

Comment: I am very new to this. How am I passing it the whole node?

Comment: template < typename elemType >
inline void BinaryTree< elemType >::remove( const elemType &e )
{
  _root->find_node( _root, e );
}

Comment: This is what my professor gave us. The only file I was supposed to change was the node.h file.